# find match of 1st word and and last

Tags: php, regex

I have a url that looks some what like this

```
for-sale/stuff/state/used-bla-bla2-bla3-bla4-(bla5)---f10-85934.html
```

i'm trying to validate the format, in my function using this regex.

```
if (preg_match('/(?:^|(?:\-))(\w+)/g', $pathInfo, $matches)) { 
  echo $digit = $matches[0]; 
}
```

`$pathInfo` is the url given above.

Basically i want to match

1. make sure the directory is `for-sale/stuff/`
2. `used-bla-bla2-bla3-bla4-(bla5)---f10-85934.html` file must start with either used/new and end with a `integer.html`
3. no spaces are allowed.

After i validate, i want to get the ID. which in this case is `85934`

Comment: you mean this `^for-sale/stuff/.+/(?:used|new)\S*\d\.html$` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
'~^for-sale/stuff/\S+/(?:used|new)\S*?(\d+)\.html$~'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jR6kW5/3)

Comment: worked fine on regex101.com, but in my code `if (preg_match('/^for-sale/stuff/\S+/(?:used|new)\S*?(\d+)\.html$/gm', $pathInfo, $matches)) {`  i get this warning  `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 't' `

Comment: nvm, got it `~^for-sale/stuff/\S+/(?:used|new)\S*?(\d+)\.html$~`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this sample piece of code and the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/gD8cF2/4):

```
$re = "~\\bfor\\-sale\\/stuff\\/[^<> ]*?\\/(?:used|new)[^/ ]*?\\-(\\d+)\\.html\\b~"; 
$str = "<a href=\"for-sale/stuff/state/used-bla-bla2-bla3-bla4-(bla5)---f10-85934.html\"></a>\n<a href=\"for-sale/stuff/state/new-bla-bla2-bla3-bla4-(bla1)-f90-12344.html\"></a>"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Regex: `\bfor\-sale\/stuff\/[^<> ]*?\/(?:used|new)[^/ ]*?\-(\d+)\.html\b`

I assume you have several URLs to validate in a variable string of text, thus I sugget using `\b`, and that the URL is inside some tag, so I'd use `[^<> ]*?` in order to limit capturing to just inside a tag.

The ID will be in the first capturing group (captured by `\d+`).
Spaces are also disallowed: `[^<> ]*?`, [^/ ]*?.

Comment: basically after i validate, i want to get the ID. which in this case is `85934`

Comment: @user2636556: I updated the regex and link. So, the first capturing group will now have the ID.